# Create list of addresses from array

Tags: sas

I'm trying to create a fuzzy matching algorithm in SAS and I am getting stuck on the mechanism to create a list of all possible address options.

I want to create a list of common address strings, ie, St, Street, Ave, Avenue, etc.

Then take the address and if any words within the string match the list of common address strings, create all possible scenarios of that address.

So for example:

101 N Main St would convert to: 
101 N Main St
101 N Main Street
101 North Main St
101 North Main Street

I can program this on a small scale, but not when I have about 100 common address strings I want in the list.

Comment: If you haven't yet, you should look at `ngrams`, which is sort of what you're doing here.  SAS has some capability of dealing with them, but there's also just a lot of info out there for how to handle some of this that might be better than this particular approach (and might give you clues for how to approach the data step programming even if the literature is mostly python/r/c).

Comment: Search on lexjansen.com and you'll find a ton of papers and code that works on cleaning up and extracting addresses. The general method is to extract into components, standardize and then re-format.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the list of common things (ST->STREET etc.) into a format.  Then you can create your array (or, perhaps, vertical dataset) by using PUT and PUTting the various words with that format, and if non-null is returned put the new bit into a new array element.

Something like:

Step 1.  Make excel file with your relationships

Step 2.  Import excel file, and use PROC FORMAT CNTLIN= option to import to a format, and ' ' for hlo=o (OTHER option)

Step 3.  Apply in datastep with something like:

```
data want;
  set have;
  do _i = 1 to countw(address);
    *use CALL SCAN to find position of i'th word and extract to _ADDCHECK;
    *use PUT with format created in step 2 to see if it matches;
    if _addcheck ne ' ' then do;
      *use CALL SCAN results combined with SUBSTR to put _ADDCHECK back in;
      output; *or store in an array if you prefer;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Then you have something that's quite flexible.

An alternate option that still works with the formats is to split the address into separate words, then use PROC TABULATE with the format and MULTILABEL option (hlo='m') to generate the larger list (this would have to be multiple rows, at first at least).